# spliting 64 bit value to fit in argument type of double

Tags: c++, c, math, floating-point-precision

I have a function for which i cannot change the syntax, say this is some library function that i am calling:

```
void schedule(double _val);

void caller() {
   uint64_t value = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
   schedule(value);
}
```

as the function schedule accepts double as the argument type, in cases where the value of the argument is greater that 52 bits ( considering double stores mantissa as 52 bit value) i loose the precision in such cases.

what i intend to do is , if the value if greater than the max value a double can hold, i need to loop for the remaining value, so that in the end it sums up to correct value.

```
    void caller() {
       uint64_t value = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
       for(count = 0; count < X ; count++) {
           schedule(Y);
       }
    }
```

i need to extract X and Y from variable 'value'.
How can this be achieved ?
My objective is not to loose the precision because of the type casting.

Comment: Does schedule have some magical property, like `schedule(x+y)` is the same as `schedule(x);schedule(y);`?

Comment: @MarcGlisse good point. Everybody seems to assume that, although it was never stated.

Comment: @MarcGlisse - could not get your point ?

Comment: @Dexter: Your question implies that one call to `schedule` can be replaced with multiple sequential calls to `schedule`. Yet you provided no explanation as to how such replacement is made. What is the "replacement rule" in this case? What is the invariant that has to be maintained? The sum of arguments should remain the same? Or something else? Without knowing that it is not possible to figure out where your `X` and `Y` are supposed to come from and what they are supposed to mean.

Comment: @AndreyT - there is no issue with the number of calls made to schedule. Only thing that needs to be maintained is that X*Y = value. Actually, the problem here relates to an event based simulation scenario. 'schedule' method invokes a notification after period of time passed as argument. This has limitation of double value type. I just need to handle cases where the value is greater that max value of double.

Comment: @Dexter: Your last comment tells us that X calls to `schedule(Y);` are equivalent to `schedule(X*Y);`. We would like to know something more general: Is `schedule(A); schedule(B);` equivalent to `schedule(A+B);`, assuming A and B are non-negative and `A+B` could be calculated and passed exactly, with no rounding errors or other arithmetic issues? Even if A or B is very large (e.g., `1u<<63`), as long as it is passed without error?

Comment: @EricPostpischil - yes

Comment: @Dexter: Okay, then my answer stands.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - the first schedule call , will agian result in error.

Comment: @Dexter: If `schedule` is passed a large value, such as 2**63, and it is passed exactly, with no error, does `schedule` work or not?

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is only losing precision in `caller` and not in `schedule`, then no loop is needed:

```
void caller() {
    uint64_t value = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
    uint64_t modulus = (uint64_t) 1 << 53;
    schedule(value - value % modulus);
    schedule(value % modulus)
}
```

In `value - value % modulus`, only the high 11 bits are significant, because the low 53 have been cleared. So, when it is converted to `double`, there is no error, and the exact value is passed to `schedule`. Similarly, `value % modulus` has only 53 bits and is converted to double exactly.

(The encoding of the significand of an IEEE-754 64-bit binary floating-point object has 52 bits, but the actual significand has 53 bits, due to the implicit leading bit.)

Note: The above may result in `schedule` being called with an argument of zero, which we have not established is permitted. If that is a problem, such a call should be skipped.

Comment: An alternative (not better, but since we are already converting to double): `double d1=value; uint64_t v1=d1; schedule(d1); schedule (value-v1);`. By the way, 32 would work just as well as 53.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: The conversion to `double` might round up, causing `d1` to exceed `value` and making `value-v1` mathematically negative. Since it is a `uint64_t`, that is wrapped, and the wrong value is passed.

Comment: Good point, which goes with the usual "don't use double when you can use an integer".

Comment: but again "value - value % modulus" won't be greater that 53 bits here ?

Comment: @Dexter: The magnitude of he value may be greater than 2**53, but it can be represented exactly as a `double` because at most 11 consecutive bits are needed to represent it. Because the point floats in floating point, the exponent tells you where the bits are and the significand tells you what those bits are. So 11 bits are easily represented even though they are high in magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

If `N` is the max integral value your `double` can represent precisely, then obviously you can use

```
Y = N
```

and

```
X = amount / Y
```

(assuming integral division). Once you finished iterating over `X` you still have to schedule the remainder

```
R = amount % Y
```

Just keep in mind that all integral calculations have to be performed within the domain of `uint64_t` type, i.e. you have to add proper suffix to the constants (`UL` or `ULL`), or use type casts to `uint64_t` or use intermediate variables of type `uint64_t`.

Of course, if your program doesn't really care how many times `schedule` is called as long as the total is correct, then you can use virtually any value for `N`, as long as it can be represented precisely. For example, you can simply set `N = 10000`.

On the other hand, if you want to minimize the number of `schedule` calls, then it be worth noting that due to "implicit 1" rule the max integer that can be represented precisely in 52 bit mantissa is `(1 << 53) - 1`.